# is it possible for a front end repository to communicate with a backend repository on localhost in gihub actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a github repo called **front-end** and another called **backend-mockdata**
The front end uses cypress to run some tests using localhost react dev server.
It needs backend-mockdata running to power the api data calls.

The issue I'm running into when deploying using a github action is that my cypress tests will fail because backend-mockdata is not running when the action is triggered.

- front-end: runs on http://localhost:3000/
- backend-mockdata: runs a ./jena/fuseki-server --loc=./gc-alldata.db /gc
- the gena server runs on (http://localhost:3030)

I have my action in the front-end

```
name: Deploy Action runner
on: [push, pull_request]
jobs:
  publish:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ./build
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: yarn

      - name: Cypress
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v4
        with:
          working-directory: ./client
          install: false
          browser: chrome
          start: yarn start
```

Is it possible to run an action in my front end that would kick off an action to start gena server runs on (http://localhost:3030) and for my cypress test to be able to run using the http://localhost:3030 in the headless workflow ?

Comment: Can you encapsulate your test backend server dependencies in docker image or docker-compose?

Comment: I could but I don't know docker so not sure how I would go about that but I can look into it. From the little I do know, wouldn't docker still need access to those files in the other repo in order to run it in its own container ?

Comment: Firstly, docker only needs access to the directory in the building process. After you publish it on any registry (docker hub is the most popular) either public or private you wouldn't need access to the repo. Then you can run the docker container as a service near your Github Actions. More here https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-containerized-services/about-service-containers

Comment: Another option is to mock API calls at all. It can be a fetch function or any function that retrieves data.

Comment: Also, I have a bit of a misunderstanding about why you use `cypress` which is an e2e testing library when by description your tests are unit (JUnit suits better).

Comment: Docker sounds like the way to go. As for the tests yes they are e2e not unit. The reason they are mocked is because I don't have access to the api for legal reasons. Once the project is complete then the client will use the api internal.

Answer (score 0):

There are two optimal solutions for conducting e2e tests with the mocked server:

- Using the Github Actions service feature(Docker)
- Use lambdas to host your fake server

Each has its own drawbacks and benefits.

### Docker

1. You build an image and publish it on one of the registries.

   1. You can use [Github Actions to automate building](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/build-and-push-docker-images) and publish your image.
   2. Registry I'll recommend 2 providers [Github registry](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-container-registry) and [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com), but of course, you can choose another one. I recommend Docker hub because it's easier to configure(it has only 2 private repos in the free version and an unlimited open one).
2. Use built an image as a service. They have good explanation for [Redis](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-containerized-services/creating-redis-service-containers) and [Postgresql](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-containerized-services/creating-postgresql-service-containers).

**Info:** I've tried a lot running [job in container](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-containerized-services/creating-postgresql-service-containers#running-jobs-in-containers), but I've problem with ports, so I recommend running jobs directly on the [runner machine](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-containerized-services/creating-postgresql-service-containers#running-jobs-directly-on-the-runner-machine)

**Disclaimer:** If you're using a private container registry don't forget to [provide it](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-09-24-github-actions-private-registry-support-for-job-and-service-containers/) in the GitHub actions

#### Example of PostgreSQL with private registry access

```yaml
name: PostgreSQL Service Example
on: push

jobs:
  # Label the runner job
  runner-job:
    # You must use a Linux environment when using service containers or container jobs
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Service containers to run with `runner-job`
    services:
      # Label used to access the service container
      postgres:
        # Docker Hub image
        image: postgres
        credentials:
          username: mona
          password: ${{ secrets.docker_hub_password}}
        # Provide the password for postgres
        env:
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
        # Set health checks to wait until postgres has started
        options: >-
          --health-cmd pg_isready
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5
        ports:
          # Maps TCP port 5432 on service container to the host
          - 5432:5432

    steps:
      # Downloads a copy of the code in your repository before running CI tests
      - name: Check out repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      # Performs a clean installation of all dependencies in the `package.json` file
      # For more information, see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci.html
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci

      - name: Connect to PostgreSQL
        # Runs a script that creates a PostgreSQL table, populates
        # the table with data, and then retrieves the data
        run: node client.js
        # Environment variables used by the `client.js` script to create
        # a new PostgreSQL table.
        env:
          # The hostname used to communicate with the PostgreSQL service container
          POSTGRES_HOST: localhost
          # The default PostgreSQL port
          POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
```

### Lambdas

You can host your mock server in Lmbdas providers:

- [AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html) supports the majority of languages including Java, Go, Node.Js, Python
- [Do Functions](https://www.digitalocean.com/products/functions) support Go, Node.Js, Python
- GCP and Azure have similar functionality and language support as AWS

Benefits:

- You pay only per invocation
- Each provider has a monthly free tier of around 1 million invocations (you don't pay for them at all)

Drawbacks:

- in special cases can not match your interests or it can be too complicated to move existing mock servers on lambdas
- need proper CI to maintain developer flexibility

### Conclusion

Both options are valid and can play better than others in certain circumstances. There is no silver bullet.